# Getting class attribute value using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I have some experience web scraping with Excel VBA and so far I can't find this solution anywhere online.  I am trying to inspect if the following div element has the text "dxm-disabled" in its class value.

`<div class="dxm-content dxm-hasText dxm-disabled" style="vertical-align:middle;" id="AcknowledgeSplitter"> .... </div>`

I know how to locate the div element using its ID but I am out of idea how to get the class value.  I have already tried doing `IE.Document.getElementById("AcknowledgeSplitter").getAttribute("class")` but I get an empty string.

Comment: Try the already given answer. If that still doesn't work please supply the url if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
IE.Document.getElementById("AcknowledgeSplitter").className
```

Comment: This worked perfectly!  So simple in the end.  Thanks Tim!